# How to get default user of jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want to get default user of jenkins by which jenkins is running its jobs.
When i did following command

```
ps aux | grep jenkins
```

It giving me following output

```
root     10530  0.1 11.5 9950744 1844716 ?     Ssl  Aug08   9:00 
/etc/alternatives/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins
-jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log
--webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100
--handlerCountMaxIdle=20
```

I am sure this is the service user who is running jenkins service.I want to know by which default user jenkins running its jobs.is there any thing on jenkins from which i can change the default user of jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Jenkins server, you can get this information from the Jenkins configuration file, which is typically stored in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins':

```
grep JENKINS_USER /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
```

The same information can also be obtained via the Jenkins Web UI (Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes), then click on a node and choose 'System Information'. Or, directly navigate to it by replacing `<jenkins_base_url>` (typically something like `https://my.company.org/jenkins`) and `<node>` with existing values in your setup:

```
<jenkins_base_url>/computer/<node>/systemInfo
```

On this page you see system properties and environment variables like:

```
user.name    jenkins
USER         jenkins
```

Comment: This api is giving me 404

Comment: Have you tried navigating to the page via Jenkins UI (Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes)?

Comment: Yes... but I didn't find anything related to that.

Comment: If you can access the server, you should find the `JENKINS_USER` in the main config file (I updated my answer accordingly)